Does any JMESPath/JQ query linter/validator tool exist at all?
I'm looking into JMESPath language and the JQ tool, as a JSON Query Language and JSON Query tool, but I wonder if there are any linters or validators to actually validate (or even give feedback) on incorrect syntaxes inside JMESPath or JQ queries.
I would preferably want to see one that I can integrate into VScode IDE. Syntax highlighting would be nice to have too. I have some fairly complex queries.
